# Cannot exectue programs within IntelliJ IDEA 11

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I upgraded to IntelliJ IDEA 11 CE and I cannot execute any tests or main programs within the IDE anymore. It is very strange as the JDK is there and will compile, but doesn't do anything when I go to run programs.

My projects are imported from a multi-module maven project and it has worked fine with previous releases.

How do I get it to run my programs and unit tests? I am having to use Eclipse instead to execute them.

Comment: IntelliJ isn't showing errors in your code at all?

Comment: IntelliJ 11 still executes tests and main programs.  (I'm using it right now.)  Your setup isn't correct.

Comment: No errors at all. I thought it would be my setup but nothing has been changed since I upgraded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems IDEA installation directory gets corrupted somehow. It happened to me unexpectedly after a week and the only thing I could do to re-enable run/debug was to **reinstall IDEA from scratch**.
Even invalidating caches or purging .IdeaIC11 directory didn't do any good.